# Github actions maven failed to clean install project because cant create resource directory

Tags: maven, github-actions, maven-clean-plugin, maven-install

Hello :) I am trying to run a pipeline on Github Actions in which I would like to clean and install a maven package, which I am trying to do like so:

```
 - name: Clean and install package
   run:  mvn clean install -X
```

When I am doing that I see the following error which causes the build to fail:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Cannot create resource output directory: /home/runner/work/calculator/calculator/backend/target/classes
```

I was wondering if someone ever had a similar issue and would maybe know why it is caused? I checked with this command who runs the job and I see that the job runs from the `'runner'`. Could it be that runners cant create folders? Or maybe there is some other issue between maven and GHA

```
Run whoami
runner
```

Comment: You can confirm by creating a directory yourself e.g. `mkdir test-dir`. See if that works. As your question doesn't include your complete workflow, it's hard to say anything about the reason.

Comment: should works - can you provide more lines from stack trace, which plugin couse such exception